# Multiple users on the same machine on the same time

Tags: networking, 18.04, multiple-monitors, sharing, vino

I have a very powerful computer that is running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver). And i want to use this computer with my colleagues in the same network at the same time using screen sharing (each person has different users and different screens at the same time). I managed to install vino and connect the computer remotely with remmina but how can i do this with multiple users at the same time?

Answer (score -1):

Here are the things worked for me.. (success using this tute  http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-vnc-server-on-ubuntu-14.04 and kudose for Charles Tassell for right directions and advice)

What I did is as follows,

(1) run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

(2)run `sudo apt-get install gnome-core xfce4 vnc4server`

(3)then add users (vncserver/unix)

```
sudo adduser test1
```

(you will have to fill details afterwards for the user, I have added 3 users (test1, test2, test3 etc for vnc server)

(4)Then you have to switch users one by one and run vncserver and add password for vncuser login ***(I have three vnc users, so that i had to repeat this for all three user test 1, test2, test3)***

```
su - test1
```

then run

```
vncserver
```

out put will be like this prompting for a vnc password..

```
You will require a password to access your desktops.

Password:
Verify:

xauth:  file /home/test1/.Xauthority does not exist
New 'server1:1 (test1)' desktop is server1:1
Creating default startup script /home/test1/.vnc/xstartup
Starting applications specified in /home/test1/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/test1/.vnc/server1:1.log
```

(5) Important : you will have to replace /home/test1/.vnc/xstartup content with below **(Else you will not get the desktop, instead you will stuck with blank screen without user interfaces or menus )**

```
vim /home/test1/.vnc/xstartup
```

and add

```
#!/bin/sh
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
startxfce4 &

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
```

(6) startup script for the vncserver was created using ["Further I will make the startup script for the vncserver like this"](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-vnc-server-on-ubuntu-14.04) section of [this tute](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-vnc-server-on-ubuntu-14.04)

```
sudo vim /etc/init.d/vncserver
```

and add below content..

```
#!/bin/bash

unset VNCSERVERARGS
VNCSERVERS=""
[ -f /etc/vncserver/vncservers.conf ] && . /etc/vncserver/vncservers.conf
prog=$"VNC server"
start() {
 . /lib/lsb/init-functions
 REQ_USER=$2
 echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
 ulimit -S -c 0 >/dev/null 2>&1
 RETVAL=0
 for display in ${VNCSERVERS}
 do
 export USER="${display##*:}"
 if test -z "${REQ_USER}" -o "${REQ_USER}" == ${USER} ; then
 echo -n "${display} "
 unset BASH_ENV ENV
 DISP="${display%%:*}"
 export VNCUSERARGS="${VNCSERVERARGS[${DISP}]}"
 su ${USER} -c "cd ~${USER} && [ -f .vnc/passwd ] && vncserver :${DISP} ${VNCUSERARGS}"
 fi
 done
}
stop() {
 . /lib/lsb/init-functions
 REQ_USER=$2
 echo -n $"Shutting down VNCServer: "
 for display in ${VNCSERVERS}
 do
 export USER="${display##*:}"
 if test -z "${REQ_USER}" -o "${REQ_USER}" == ${USER} ; then
 echo -n "${display} "
 unset BASH_ENV ENV
 export USER="${display##*:}"
 su ${USER} -c "vncserver -kill :${display%%:*}" >/dev/null 2>&1
 fi
 done
 echo -e "\n"
 echo "VNCServer Stopped"
}
case "$1" in
start)
start $@
;;
stop)
stop $@
;;
restart|reload)
stop $@
sleep 3
start $@
;;
condrestart)
if [ -f /var/lock/subsys/vncserver ]; then
stop $@
sleep 3
start $@
fi
;;
status)
status Xvnc
;;
*)
echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|condrestart|status}"
exit 1
esac
```

to make it an executable run the following..

```
chmod +x /etc/init.d/vncserver
```

(7) To make vnc desktop sessions allocated for users at start up automatically, create following script in /etc/vncserver

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/vncserver
sudo vim /etc/vncserver/vncservers.conf
```

add this in vncservers.conf (this is because i have my users as test1, test2, test3 change it according to )

```
VNCSERVERS="3:test3 2:test2 1:test1"
VNCSERVERARGS[1]="-geometry 1024x768"
VNCSERVERARGS[2]="-geometry 1024x768"
VNCSERVERARGS[3]="-geometry 1024x768"
```

(8) Then run

```
sudo `update-rc.d vncserver defaults 99`
```

(9) reboot server (you are almost done by now) step 10 and the rest is how to login part

(10)download http://www.realvnc.com/download/viewer/

enter servername/ipaddress and session id 
for example my server is 172.16.70.17 and if i use 172.16.70.17:2 it will login to test2 user desktop.. and 172.16.70.17:3 will login to test3 user desktop like wise

make sure encryption to be selected "Prefer off"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQ36F.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmMoc.png

Then you can access your desktop and applications in this manner..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN7UK.png

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but xfce doesnt work for me since i could not be able to start my simulation software with that environment. i need figure this out with screen sharing using vino.

Comment: @mystic09 Vino is for desktop *sharing* - if you want each user to have their own desktop session, you need a differeent kind of VNC server (`vnc4server` or `tightvncserver`). Users don't *have* to use XFCE, they can configure their `xstartup` files to use a desktop of their choice (although "heavy" desktops may perform poorly over your network - that's why XFCE/LXDE are often recommended).

Comment: You have to set vito Vino to use unique ports for each user instance, then manually logged in to all local user accounts (starting their Vino server instances). But this isn't enough due GUI session controls locks. I suggest you to use TigerVNC, anyway you have update .vnc/xstartup to unset session variables before starting a window manager.
   
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

Follow more helpful/complete instruction at  
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TigerVNC#Running_vncserver_for_virtual_(headless)_sessions    the easyest way is to use lightdm.

Comment: Maybe it's better to try to figure out a way to let your program run in a different envronment.